# Formatting a DVD-R

Tags: 14.04, dvd, format

I tried burning an .iso image onto a DVD-R disc but it didn't burn correctly. And no matter how I go about erasing it's content I get a error that says the disc has a read-only file system. How would I go about formatting the disc to the original state (before anything was burned on it)?

Comment: Questions about Ubuntu 14.04 are no longer supported on this site. Perhaps try Ubuntu Forums. However, I vote to keep this question open, because the wrong Header is called up. This question is about an official Ubuntu flavor that is under Extended Security Maintenance and is off-topic on AU.

Answer (score 2):

DVD-R disc is only read for. 
Once information has been written on this you can't delete or re-write it.

Comment: To format and rewrite, you need a DVD-RW.

Answer (score 0):

Take a sharpie and black out the barcode in the center of the disk where it says something like dr-o12345678, enjoy